# Why is it true that the multiplication operator in a reproducing kernel Hilbert space is always continuous?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

In my functional analysis I was met with this seemingly trivial theorem on RKHS

> If $ \mathbb{H} $ is a reproducing Kernel Hilbert Space and we have a multiplier $ \phi $ meaning it satisfies $ \forall f \in \mathbb{H} : \phi f \in \mathbb{H} $ and it is claimed the multiplication operator on $ \mathbb{H} $ is continuous.

One source says this follows from the closed graph theorem which I cannot sseem to so easily apply here, and another source said this is namely due to the reproducing kernel property with the inequality:

> $\langle \phi f, K_x \rangle$ = $\phi(x) \langle  f, K_x \rangle$

This does not show me how convergence in norm of the arguments $ f_n $ leads to convergence in norm of $ \phi f_n $ so this is where I am stuck and truly need help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closed graph theorem indeed suggests itself: Suppose that $f_n\to f$ and $\phi f_n\to g$ in norm. We must show that then $g=\phi f$. This follows from
$$
g(x)=\langle K_x, g\rangle = \lim\, \langle K_x, \phi f_n\rangle =\phi(x) \lim\, \langle K_x, f_n\rangle =\phi(x)f(x) .
$$

Comment: Thank you I get it now finally